# Compile bunch of files in folder to one JS file (per-folder)?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

TypeScript allows to compile one TS in one JS, or all TS in one JS. The first apporach is too fragmented for us (since we would need to reference them all in correct order from html), the latter works but then even single page downloads and compiles all code for all pages, that appears to us as wasting.
In fact we have some ~300 TS files and only 12 pages (single-page-apps). All files for one page we have in one folder.
Is it somehow possible to tell TS compiler, that we want TS files in a folder to be compiled to single JS file (named after the folder) ?
We use VS2017, TS2.1, CSPROJ schema.
Thx for ideas. Jiri

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the **[Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier)** extension in your vs2017
   using the nuget package or direct download.
2. In the solution select all the files you want to compile to single
   file.
3. Right click and select **Bundle & Minifier** option as shown in the screenshot below,

[image]

Comment: How does it play with automated build using TFS (XAML build) and work in team ?

Comment: You need to write a gulp or grunt file that makes your work done during build

Comment: OK. This is a way I'd like to avoid as long as possible. So TS is not capable of that by itself, only when scripted.